# Unauthorized Python Requests using Mohawk

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get a POST requests through python. Server side dev provided me with an auth key ie: short124 and a long key. They were generated by Mohawk library. Dev from server side gave me a code example:

```
import requests
from mohawk import Sender

creds = {'id': short,'key':very_long_key,'algorithm':'sha256'}
auth_session = Sender( credentials = creds, url = url, method = 'POST',always_hash_content=False)
headers = {'Authorization' : auth_session.request_header}
r = requests.post(url,data = input, headers = headers, verify = False)
print(r)
```

Unfortunately I get 401 error (unauthorized) with the credentials provided,

Can anyone give me some advide?

Comment: url and input variables exists somewhere ... I just giving the request example part.

Answer (score 0):

The way it's being used seem correct. I would double check the credentials and the url.

Also consider using [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) it will make code formatting a breeze.